# Does $Y_i=(X_i-a)^2$ is i.i.d imply $X_i$ i.i.d.?

Tags: probability

I think this is true because for $Y_i=k$ you always could find one or more $X_i$ let $(X_i-a)^2=k$ so $P(Y_1=k)=P(X_1=t)=P(X_2=t)=P(Y_2=t)$ and $P(Y_1=a,Y_2=b)=P(X_1=t,X_2=K)=P(X_1=t)P(X_2=K)=P(Y_1=a)P(Y_2=b)$ so $Y_i$ are i.i.d Am i right?

Comment: If $(X_i)$ is i.i.d so is $(f(X_i))$ for any measurable function $f$. In particular this is true for continuous functions $f$.

Comment: that means Xi are iid and f is a continuous function, then f(Xi) are i.i.d right?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that $Y_i \to \sqrt{Y_i + a}$ is not even a function because we don't know whether or not the $X_i$ is positive or not, so the square root is not a function. In particular, a counterexample exploiting this is shown below.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Let us suppose that $X_1=X_2$ are two dependent random variables taking values $a\pm 1$ with equal probabilities.

Then $Y_i=(X_i-a)^2\equiv 1$ and therefore $Y_1,Y_2$  are independent as degenerate r.v.'s. Nevertheless $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent.